# Change sql server query so you don't have to specify all levels to the database

Tags: sql-server, database

What I want to do is instead of writing:

```
Select something From [Parent].[dbo].[Table]
```

I want to declare the first 2 before I write the query, so when I have to use several `selects` I don't have to specify `[parent].[dbo]` all the time. What I remember is that you can do something like this:

```
use [parent].[dbo]
select something From tabel
```

This seems to generate a warning 102, at the `"."`. I've tried googling this but all I get is "use" while doing generated queries, nothing to do with database names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dbo part is implied. Just do this:

```
use [parent]
select something From tabel
```

As Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out, the dbo part is only [implied](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx) if dbo is the user's default schema.

Comment: Sigh, yes, i had a warning then when i did it that tabel wasn't recognized, but they wrote Organi **z** ation instead of Organi **s** ation

Comment: Lovely. I love spelling mistakes; caused me a lot of grief as well.

Comment: The dbo part is only implied if dbo is the user's default schema. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx

Comment: well, it's my fourth day at my first job, and i've mostly searched my way through code and data, so spelling mistakes really are a pain when doing that.

Comment: @Damien good point. I'll add that so I don't confuse people. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Parent must be your Database.

So if you want to use a particular database without specifying it:

`use [DataBase]`

DBO is implied, but if you want to use another schema, you will need to specify the schema in your SQL, ala `newschema.Table1`

In case you aren't using it, you can also reduce the clutter in your code by using aliases for your tables, ala

`SELECT a.Column1, a.Column2

FROM table1 a JOIN

     table2 b ON a.Column1 = b.Column1

WHERE a.column1 = 'SomeValue'`

where the `a` that follows the table1 is an alias for table1, basically your giving the table a nickname for this query. Same thing for the b, it is an alias for table2. This is much less cluttered than `SELECT table1.Column1, table1.Column2 FROM table1`